# PowerPivot return value of last date for each Uniquw

Tags: powerpivot

Good day everyone,

So I've been struggling with this calculation in PowerPivot, where I want the formula to return the last project status for each project, from the last date. I have used a few formulas to at least get the last date for each project number, but have not managed to get that right either. I've tried variants of LASTNONBLANK, MAX, LASTDATE etc. but these all miss the crucial bit where it does it for each project number.

=CALCULATE(MAX(GetTimeSheetData[Date]),ALL(GetTimeSheetData))
=LASTNONBLANK(GetTimeSheetData[Date],GetTimeSheetData[Code])

.....and many others.

I have the file on the link below that shows what I need to do, any help will be most welcome......I'm busy going crazy!!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B29yA0i2Te9ycFVSclBuZUVzSUU/view?usp=sharing

Thanks!!

Llewellyn

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the max date:

```
=CALCULATE( MAXA( GetTimeSheetData[Date]), ALLEXCEPT(GetTimeSheetData,GetTimeSheetData[Code]))
```

This code would get you the last status in a calculated column:

```
=CALCULATE(
     VALUES ( GetTimeSheetData[Project Status]),
     FILTER( ALLEXCEPT(GetTimeSheetData, GetTimeSheetData[Code], GetTimeSheetData[CalculatedColumn1]), 
                      GetTimeSheetData[Code] = EARLIER( GetTimeSheetData[Code]) &&
                      GetTimeSheetData[Date] = CALCULATE( MAX( GetTimeSheetData[Date]), 
                                                                                              ALLEXCEPT(GetTimeSheetData, GetTimeSheetData[Code], GetTimeSheetData[CalculatedColumn1]),
                                                                                              GetTimeSheetData[Code] = EARLIER( GetTimeSheetData[Code]))))
```

This code would get you a calculated field rather than utilizing a column:

```
Current Status:=CALCULATE(
     VALUES ( GetTimeSheetData[Project Status]),
     FILTER( ALLEXCEPT(GetTimeSheetData, GetTimeSheetData[Code]), 
                      GetTimeSheetData[Date] = CALCULATE( MAX( GetTimeSheetData[Date]), 
                                                                                              ALLEXCEPT(GetTimeSheetData, GetTimeSheetData[Code]))))
```

Either way, for the last example of taking the last status, you still need a manner of identifying which one was the true last.  In this case, I would suggest either a) a timestamp rather than a date or b) another identifying field.